# Sharekit iOS UIActionsheet, Screen flashes when app sent to background

Tags: iphone, ios

I have implemented sharekit in the app I am making.  In my final testing, I notice when I have the SHKActionsheet displayed and the user presses the home button to put the app in the background the app fully goes to the background and then the screen flashes my underlying view that the actionsheet was on top of.

I have the following code to detect if my app is being sent into the background:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(dimissSharekit)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
 object:NULL];
```

At which point my dimissSharekit method calls:

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1
                                  animated:NO];
```

I can't figure out what the flash is about:

- Even if I leave the actionsheet visible when I got to background I get the flash of my underlying view
- I am guessing it has something to do with the activity indicator that sharekit brings up when it successfully saves or shares.
- All works fine, it just doesn't look good when this happens.

Comment: I also notice if I bring up the mail composer through sharekit and then click cancel, so the actionsheet showing the save draft or delete it is shown and then got to the background, I get the same screen flash.  It really seems like this is tied to uiactionsheets some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deployed to my device and this doesn't happen on my hardware.  It only occurs on the simulator.  So, I'll ignore this behaviour and say it is something that is a result of the imperfect behaviour of the simulator itself.